# set_time_limit ( ), Die ( ) can this function be use to cancel a file upload in php

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

Can `this => set_time_limit ()`,  `Die()` be used to cancel a file Upload.

i.e When user clicks a button `set_time_limit ()` function will execute.

Will it Stop the Upload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be better to use a Javascript solution to accomplish this. Of course, since it is client-side people can get around it. If it is a security issue, don't rely on Javascript. If you run Apache, you can try [mod_reqtimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html), however this is for request headers, so I'm not entirely sure if the file upload will be part of this or not.

Edit:
There is also the Apache [Timeout directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#timeout) and [KeepAliveTimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout) which look more promising.

Edit2:
I just stumbled upon [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php). It seems like this is exactly what you are looking for (assuming PHP >= 5.4). And from one of the comments, for previous versions you can use [this](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress).

Answer (score 2):

It won't

Php itself doesn't take any part in file uploading progress. When webserver starts running your script - the file is already uploaded

Comment: Is there any way that we can cancel the upload.

Comment: @Avin Varghese: from which side? Doubtfully, without any special webserver modules

Comment: I am working on a script which can be used for Server to Server File Transfer. [Apache Server]

Comment: @Avin Varghese: this still explains nothing. You better explain the whole workflow, with elaboration of why you need to be able to terminate uploading process

Comment: User starts upload [Eg: File size:2GB] at the middle of the upload process user change his decision to cancel the upload.

Comment: @Avin Varghese: he could just close the tab/browser

Comment: If the user close the tab/browser the Upload will process until the whole file is transferred.

Comment: @Avin Varghese: So a user triggering the script causes the server to upload a certain file to another server? Did I understand it right?

Comment: @Avin Varghese: how the process is organized? Is it synchronous or asynchronous (from the user's browser point of view)? How exactly one server sends the data to another?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, there are no way for PHP to "cancel" an upload. As far as PHP is informed about your upload, the uploading process is done.

However, that is just a guess, but as there is a way to create a progress bar using APC (then check the upload process), you may be able to stop it. But I'm really unsure since the check (ie: the progress bar) is ran in a different php process which can't interact with the currently uploaded file.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way Request and Reponses work you will always have to wait for the data to be delivered before you can do anymore with it, including cancelling the upload. You can, as @Mike said set a timeout but that isn't really cancelling the upload, that's basically telling php that hey this user is taking to long to do something so tell them we aren't waiting anymore. You would be better off using ajax to do something like this.

Comment: Will check it with ajax. Thanks